Ethers JS transaction not resolving on AWS EC2 instance
I am using ethers.js which runs on Elastic Beanstalk (EC2 t3.medium for instance). The code works perfectly on my local machine and also on AWS EC2.
However, there is always a problem after a few hours. On AWS,, especially, this section of code gets stuck at tx.wait(). The server is still running and answers other requests. It just quits at tx.await().
After restarting the app server, everything works fine. Just a few hours later, it did not work again. Thus, I assume, that there era no errors in code or blockchain-related errors.
Here is the code, for reference:
let tx = await myContract.transfer(
      address1,
      address2,
      nftToken,
      1,
      "0x"
    );
console.log("waiting for receipt");
receipt = await tx.wait();
console.log("transaction hash: " + receipt.hash);

I have checked all the logs, but did not find a relevant issue. The code and setup is correct, as it works after a restart of the app server. It's just weird behaviour, and I cannot figure out, why this happens?
I assume it is related to an EC2/EB configuration. I would appreciate every idea and help. Please let me know if certain logs are in your interest.

You said that it gets stuck and that it quits, which is a little contradictory. What actually happens? Possibly related: https://github.com/ethers-io/ethers.js/issues/945

I mean, that the server is still running and answers to other requests. But it does not proceed to the next line in this particular function, and the transaction hash is never printed. It just keeps stuck in tx.wait(). I also checked the issue you mentioned, but there is no specific solution, and actually my transactions work after a server restart. So I think it is AWS related.

You're not really doing this correctly IMO.
You're not calculating with a gas margin or a gas estimate so you're locking the instance.
You're awaiting for the Tx to complete instead of just initializing it and logging the hash
const gasEstimate = await myContract.estimateGas.transfer(
  address1,
  address2,
  nftToken,
  1,
  "0x"
);

const gasLimit = gasEstimate.mul(Math.floor(1.2 * 100)).div(100); 

const tx = await myContract.transfer(
  address1,
  address2,
  nftToken,
  1,
  "0x",
  {
    gasLimit: gasLimit,
  }
);

// You should be able to get the hash immediately without waiting for the tx to complete
console.log("Transaction hash:", tx.hash);

If you don't provide a gas margin and the price of gas swings it will lock the sending account, and im not sure the future transactions will complete since you have a tx in the mem pool with a nonce prior.
